# One volume of something

Tags: solutions

I am following some protocols for a reaction and after diluting my substrate in a solution I need to precipitate it in methanol. 
For this I need to pour my solution into "one volume" of methanol-

What I do not understand is what is meant by 'one volume'. Is a measurement of quantity.

The protocol can be found under the *Sulfation of cellulose* part of the methods section in:
R. G. Schweiger, “Polysaccharide sulfates. I. cellulose sulfate with a high degree of substitution,” Carbohydr. Res., vol. 21, 219–228, 1972 ([DOI: 10.1016/S0008-6215(00)82148-5](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0008621500821485)).

Comment: Welcome to Chem SE! If you have any questions about the site, visit the [help]. It might help people to answer this and make the answer more applicable to others if you include a little more detail about the procedure you are following. Best of luck in getting an answer!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it means to use a volume of methanol equal to the volume of your solution, such that you would roughly (volumes aren't additive) double the total volume of your solution. Unfortunately, I don't have full free access to the article you cited so I don't have the full context of the section in question.

Answer (score 1):

If the reaction till "then" was a solution of, say 500 mL, than the addition of the next liquid – from your writing, it reads like it were methanol – should be equally just 500 mL. (And 500 divided by 500 were ... just 1).

Maybe adding *more* than one part of methanol would no longer lead to (this much / this clean) precipitation intended, as methanol alone is quite a good solvent of your precipitate*), too.

*) Intentionally leaving open, if the precipitate is an impurity to be removed, or really refers to the product *to be isolated*.  You have the literature reference.